# Remove div from html - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove the `DIV` after nav and keep the menu simple like `nav > ul > li`

I tried `unwrap` but it doesn't work.

Here is the HTML structure

```
<nav>
  <div class="menu-headermenu-container">
    <ul id="menu-headermenu-1" class="menu">
      <li><a href="corporate-training/">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is this page public so we can poke at it? Not many details here.

Comment: actually this is page not public, working within local

Comment: @sorak the code that you need to poke at is in the question.

Comment: I thought perhaps it was requesting modifications that would not break a functional dropdown menu, which would require examining the associated JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically need to replace the div with its inner content

```
$(".menu-headermenu-container").replaceWith($("#menu-headermenu-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove the div WITHOUT the content: https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

```
 $(".menu-headermenu-container").contents().unwrap();
```

to remove the div WITH the content: https://api.jquery.com/remove/

```
 $(".menu-headermenu-container").remove();
```

Comment: this will remove the `nav`, and OP clearly says they want to remove only the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) as:

```js
$("div.menu-headermenu-container").contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="menu-headermenu-container">
    <ul id="menu-headermenu-1" class="menu">
      <li><a href="corporate-training/">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.unwrap()` method removes **the element's parent**.

`$('#menu-headermenu-1').unwrap();`

Plnkr example [unwrap() demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DvwvCK4dyl7h9e83RNZw?p=preview)

Comment: Did you apply .unwrap() method to the children, here the ```#menu-headermenu-1``` to remove the div

Comment: In the plnkr example I provided inspect Menu Item and see that there is no div in the element hierarchy. Code in script.js

Answer (score 0):

Just use `unwrap()` to `ul#menu-headermenu-1`.

> **unwrap()** remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

```js
$('ul#menu-headermenu-1').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="menu-headermenu-container">
    <ul id="menu-headermenu-1" class="menu">
      <li><a href="corporate-training/">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("nav").find(".menu-headermenu-container").contents().unwrap();
})
```

```css
.menu-headermenu-container{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="menu-headermenu-container">
    <ul id="menu-headermenu-1" class="menu">
      <li><a href="corporate-training/">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```